# QT vs wxwidget vs MFC

Tags: qt, user-interface, mfc, cross-platform

Which is the best cross platform development stack for GUI.

QT + c++

or wxWidget + c++

or wxWidget + python

or MFC for windows and GTK for Linux ...

What is the best choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on your background and requirements.

If your other hobbies include being tied up whipped then MFC is probably for you.

If you are a recovering MFC programmer then wxwidgets is a very similar (but cross platform and nicer) alternative.

Qt is the current popular C++ gui library of choice. It's cross-platform, including a nice web-ish markup version for mobile phones, it uses more modern C++ concepts

Both Qt and wx are available under under LGPL type licenses and have bindings to a range of languages including python

Comment: +1 for "tied up whipped". I started on MFC, but soon ran away to Qt in fear.

Comment: +1 So true about MFC. My programmer life is much better since I develop GUI apps in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on MFC, QT, and wxWidgets . All of them are good, but for cross platform stuff I  prefer wxWdigets over QT. The free QT designer is pathetic, whereas the wxFormBuilder is great.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on porting several large MFC applications over to Qt and it feels like... being tied up and whipped.  So I would agree that you should stay away from MFC if you possibly can and even if you are doing windows stuff you should use XAML.